# Using two jcarousels and having one influence the other

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, jcarousel

I set up the sorgalla jcarousel plugin, what I am attempting to do is have two instances of the carousel where one infuences the other. One will have a block/vertical style and the other will have a horizontal style.

Unfortunately Im only beginning to learn Javascript and Jquery, so Im not too sure how to procede from here, any helping advice as to where I could at least have a look would be great.

Here is the function being called twice...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
  start: 2, // Configuration goes here
    wrap: "circular",
    auto: 1,
    scroll: 1,

});
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#second-carousel').jcarousel({
    start: 2, // Configuration goes here
    wrap: "circular",
    auto: 1,
    scroll: 1,

});
});
</script>
```

Here is where I actually insert the jcarousels...

```
<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test2</li>

    </li>
</ul>

<ul id="second-carousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test2</li>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way I can sync the two up, so when I press the direction nav for the top one it also controls the second one?
Here is the site where they are being tested... 
http://gonuts.ie/?page_id=99

Ultimately my aim is to achieve what http://www.skysports.com have at the top of their page, perhaps there is a much easier way of going about it Im not sure.
Thanks again.

Comment: IMHO, get a different carousel plugin.  `wrap: "circular"` is famously buggy/broken in this one.

Comment: That Skysports is a single carousel not two.

Comment: Thanks Rick, after a bit more googling, I believe the term is "multi carousel", I found one tutorial on building one so Ill try that before posting an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to link two jCarousels to be like the Skysports site (noting Rick Calder's comment that the Skysports example is a single carousel).

```
var carousel_2;
$('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    start: 1,
    wrap: "circular",
    scroll: 1,
    itemFirstInCallback: {
        onBeforeAnimation: function(carousel, item, index, action) {
            if (carousel_2) {
                carousel_2[action]();
            }
        }
    }
});
$('#second-carousel').jcarousel({
    start: 2,
    wrap: "circular",
    scroll: 1,
    vertical: true,
    buttonNextHTML: null,
    buttonPrevHTML: null,
    initCallback: function(c) {
        carousel_2 = c;
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TM96s/4/)**

Testing in Opera, and with reference to Sparky672's comment, I didn't get any problems with `wrap:"circular"`.

Comment: Worked like a charm thank you , I think I need to understand `itemFirstInCallback' as I really dont know what I (or moreso you) did there.

Comment: I found `itemFirstInCallback` in the [jCarousel documentation](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/). It is one of several callback-pairs, which offer the possibility of attaching handlers to events that occur as the carousel transitions. Each callback-pair comprises `onBeforeAnimation` and `onAfterAnimation`. TBH, the documentation could be better and my solution was devised in part by trial and error. Try changing `onBeforeAnimation` to `onAfterAnimation` for a slightly different effect.

Comment: Looking at it again, I've just realised that the solution only works correctly for the 'next' action. **[This version](http://jsfiddle.net/TM96s/4/)** works correctly for both 'next' and 'prev'.

Comment: thanks Beetroot, was checking it this morning and noticed that, I wouldnt have known where to begin in terms of fixing it!

Comment: For anyone who comes along later, I have edited the answer above.

Comment: Hi Beetroot, Im wondering could I ask you for a small bit more help on something regarding this if you have time. Muchly appreciated

Comment: Hi Adrian, I should have recognized your code in the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137351/variable-not-defined-in-javascript#comment19576155_14137351). Are you still having difficulties?

Comment: Hi Beetroot, Im having one final problem, I built pagination for this but I cant seem to get the pagination to sync up the same way , I can see why this is so but am unsure how to resolve it.

The question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124286/external-pagination-put-multi-jcarousel-out-of-sync)

Comment: I appreciate your help and if you can help me with this feel free to answer my bounty [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974574/jquery-jcarousel-how-to-add-control-buttons) with the code thats being used and take the +50.Thanks again