# jquery jcarousel how to add control buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I am currently working on a site,that uses Sorgilla jquery jcarousel, there are two sliders working together.

```
var carousel_2;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#right-carousel').jcarousel({
    start: 1, // Configuration goes here
    wrap: "circular",
    scroll: 1,
    auto:3,
    vertical:true,

    itemFirstInCallback: {
    onBeforeAnimation: function(carousel, item, index, action) {
        if (carousel_2) {
            carousel_2[action]();
        }



            }
        }
    });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    start: 3, // Configuration goes here
    wrap: "circular",
    scroll: 1,
    auto:3,
    vertical:false,
    buttonNextHTML: null,
    buttonPrevHTML: null,
    initCallback: function(c) {
    carousel_2 = c;
}
});
```

});

This works as it should but I am wondering is it possible to add external controls with the set up I am using. Unfortunately Im quite new to jquery so still learning.

What Im looking to do is add buttons underneath the carousel that behave like pagination, here is an example...
http://truelogic.org/multicarousel.php
or http://www.skyports.com

here is the site im working on 
http://hartyinternational.hailstormcommerce.com/

Ideally if I could get those pagination buttons working similar to above, itd be great.

I have this css set up underneath the carousel.

```
.jcarousel-pagination {
width:100px;
height:40px;
position:absolute;
right:100px;
bottom:0px;
background:#000;

}

.jcarousel-pagination a {
font-size: 75%;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 0 5px;
margin: 0 0 5px 0;
border: 1px solid #fff;
color: #eee;
background-color: #4088b8;
font-weight: bold; 
}
```

Here is some documentation... http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

I was considering adding this code to the function inside `initCallback:` but unsure how to get it working or how to tell it what button represents what slide...

```
                jQuery('.jcarousel-pagination a').bind('click', function() {
            carousel.scroll(jQuery.jcarousel.intval(jQuery(this).text()));
            return false;
            });
```

Any help would be great, I know its a bit of a general question, but im not sure where to start
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you want to do with the external button..please, can you explain it with more precision? I think that there are something that worked well in this framework's callback.

Comment: apologies, I realised I completely left out exactly what Im trying to do, im going to edit the post now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy/Paste the below code on a temp web page, make sure that the page the Javascript points to your folder where they are located and this should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--
  jQuery library
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<!--
  jCarousel library
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<!--
  jCarousel skin stylesheet
-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../skins/tango/skin.css" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">

/**
 * Additional styles for the controls.
 */
.jcarousel-control {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.jcarousel-control a {
    font-size: 75%;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #eee;
    background-color: #4088b8;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.jcarousel-control a:focus,
.jcarousel-control a:active {
    outline: none;
}

.jcarousel-scroll {
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.jcarousel-scroll form {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.jcarousel-scroll select {
    font-size: 75%;
}

#mycarousel-next,
#mycarousel-prev {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-size: 11px;
}

</style>



<script type="text/javascript">

// for #mycarousel
function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel) {
    jQuery('.jcarousel-control a').bind('click', function() {
        carousel.scroll(jQuery.jcarousel.intval(jQuery(this).text()));
        return false;
    });
};
// end for #mycarousel

// for #right-carousel
function right_carousel_initCallback(carousel) {
    jQuery('.jcarousel-control-right a').bind('click', function() {
        carousel.scroll(jQuery.jcarousel.intval(jQuery(this).text()));
        return false;
    });
};
// end for #right-carousel


jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var carousel_2;

jQuery('#right_carousel').jcarousel({
    start: 1, // Configuration goes here
    wrap: "circular",
    scroll: 1,
    auto:3,
    vertical:true,
    initCallback: right_carousel_initCallback,
    itemFirstInCallback: {
    onBeforeAnimation: function(carousel, item, index, action) {
        if (carousel_2) {
            carousel_2[action]();
                                                                                                      }
                                }
                                      }
         });


jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    start: 3, // Configuration goes here
    wrap: "circular",
    scroll: 1,
    auto:3,
    vertical:false,
    initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,
    buttonNextHTML: null,
    buttonPrevHTML: null,

});

});
</script>


</head>

<body>

<div id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
    <div class="jcarousel-control">
      <a href="#">1</a>
      <a href="#">2</a>
      <a href="#">3</a>
      <a href="#">4</a>
      <a href="#">5</a>
      <a href="#">6</a>
      <a href="#">7</a>
      <a href="#">8</a>
      <a href="#">9</a>
      <a href="#">10</a>
    </div>

    <ul>
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/66/199481236_dc98b5abb3_s.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/75/199481072_b4a0d09597_s.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/57/199481087_33ae73a8de_s.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/77/199481108_4359e6b971_s.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481143_3c148d9dd3_s.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/72/199481203_ad4cdcf109_s.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481218_264ce20da0_s.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/69/199481255_fdfe885f87_s.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/60/199480111_87d4cb3e38_s.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/70/229228324_08223b70fa_s.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="jcarousel-scroll">
      <form action="">
        <a href="#" id="mycarousel-prev">&laquo; Prev</a>
        <select>
          <option value="1">Scroll 1 item per click</option>
          <option value="2">Scroll 2 items per click</option>
          <option value="3">Scroll 3 items per click</option>
          <option value="4">Scroll 4 items per click</option>
          <option value="5">Scroll 5 items per click</option>
        </select>
        <a href="#" id="mycarousel-next">Next &raquo;</a>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>


<!-- second one -->


<div id="right_carousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
    <div class="jcarousel-control-right">
      <a href="#">1</a>
      <a href="#">2</a>
      <a href="#">3</a>
      <a href="#">4</a>
      <a href="#">5</a>
      <a href="#">6</a>
      <a href="#">7</a>
      <a href="#">8</a>
      <a href="#">9</a>
      <a href="#">10</a>
    </div>

    <ul>
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/66/199481236_dc98b5abb3_s.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/75/199481072_b4a0d09597_s.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/57/199481087_33ae73a8de_s.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/77/199481108_4359e6b971_s.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481143_3c148d9dd3_s.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/72/199481203_ad4cdcf109_s.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481218_264ce20da0_s.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/69/199481255_fdfe885f87_s.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/60/199480111_87d4cb3e38_s.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/70/229228324_08223b70fa_s.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="jcarousel-scroll">
      <form action="">
        <a href="#" id="mycarousel-prev">&laquo; Prev</a>
        <select>
          <option value="1">Scroll 1 item per click</option>
          <option value="2">Scroll 2 items per click</option>
          <option value="3">Scroll 3 items per click</option>
          <option value="4">Scroll 4 items per click</option>
          <option value="5">Scroll 5 items per click</option>
        </select>
        <a href="#" id="mycarousel-next">Next &raquo;</a>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually they use this function to rotate

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.lnkDot').click(function(){alert(1)
        var img = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        var id = img.substring(img.length-1);

        var currId = currentDot;
        var i = 0;
        var start= 0;
        var stop = 0;

        if (parseInt(currId) < parseInt(id)) {
            start = currId;
            stop = id;
        }
        else {
            start= id;
            stop = currId;
        }
        for (i = start; i<= stop; i++) {
            actionFromDot = true;

            var carousel = jQuery('#mycarousel').data('jcarousel');
            carousel.next();

        }
        currentDot = id;

        return false;
    });
});
```

What they do is, when they click on the pagination they takes the id of the current element and get the number (var id = img.substring(img.length-1);).

Once they get the number they will have `start` and `end` position to rotate (Start position they calculate from global variable `currentDot`).

Later the make clicked id is `currentDot`

Change your pagination links like this.

```
<a href="#" id='page1' class='lnkDot'>1</a>
<a href="#" id='page2' class='lnkDot'>2</a>
<a href="#" id='page3' class='lnkDot'>3</a>
```

Comment: Thank you Sahal, do you think its possible to implement this function into my code?

Comment: Better you do one thing. You can save the page of  http://truelogic.org/multicarousel.php - Ctrl + s. and see how it works.

Comment: sorry for confusion, im not quite sure where to start at for implementing this into my code, so I changed those pag links, but how do I get the above function to apply to my links? Once its working I can worry about styling. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you update my code and try ? just pot that pagination links and javascript.

Comment: I tried but it didnt work, im not sure is it failing to identify the ids perhaps? Here is my site... hartyinternational.hailstormcommerce.com

Comment: Give this as global javascript variable  `var currentDot = 1`

Comment: You have done it wrong, give currentDot  outside the jquery call

Comment: Put your click function inside jquery ready `jQuery('.lnkDot').click(function(){` Now you have put outside

Comment: thanks, im getting closer, right now , it is simply applying the next action no matter which button I click. If I could get each button specific to each slide it would be great. The skyports one does this. but that other doesnt actually do it I just I realized.

Comment: Hi Sahal, im wondering if you could still assist me as I am looking to have this like the Skysports one where I can actually choose.

Comment: Its just that doesnt really solve the problem, I could take out most of that function code and still have what its doing now.