# J Carousel Bullet Controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, jcarousel

I am trying to input the bullet function on my JCarousel. All banners are appearing back-end, but when trying to navigate the banners using the bullet function does not work. The bullets are visible but are inactive. Any idea on the function code to rectify this and enable the buttons to function to allow me to click on different banners? Or even a point in the right direction?

```
<div class="banners">
<div class="pager jcarousel-control"><a class="jcarousel-next" href="#">1</a><a href="#">2</a><a href="#">3</a></div>
<div class="holder">
<div class="slider">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.flukenetworks.com/Fiber-Certification-Process?ls=CMS&amp;lsd=6steps"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/Banners/Fluke-Fibre-Process.jpg"}}" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="http://http://www.cmsplc.com/dymo-xtl-trade-in/"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/Banners/Dymo_XTL_Banner.jpg"}}" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.cmsplc.com/fluke-networks-dtx-upgrade-offer/"><img src="{{media   url="wysiwyg/Fluke_DTX_Buy_Back_2015.jpg"}}" alt="" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery jcarousel how to add control buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974574/jquery-jcarousel-how-to-add-control-buttons)

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a Fiddle so that we can assist.
In the meantime try;

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        $('.jcarousel').jcarousel();
        $('.jcarousel-pagination')
                .on('jcarouselpagination:active', 'a', function () {
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                })
                .on('jcarouselpagination:inactive', 'a', function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                })
                .jcarouselPagination();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

As used on the official example here: http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/basic/#4

Comment: Hi Kapeesh, hope you are well. I am pretty new to HTML and JavaScript. Where do I find the JS for the above. The link youve provided me with is exactly what I would like to achieve.@kapeeshmanilal